# Flagging comments on articles throws an error

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, collectives, articles

When flagging a comment under an article as NLN, I get

> An error occurred during flagging

The request is a POST request to https://stackoverflow.com/flags/comments/120534563/add/39 which returns code 500 and the HTML page for code 500.

Comment: That's for pointing this out, we'll look into it and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

Articles are a new(ish) thing, and flagging under them even more so, so there were a couple of safe-guards that weren't taking Article-type posts into consideration. Basically, the backend was going "You can't flag things that aren't related to questions or answers, my friend. There are *rules*."

We patched as many of these as we could find, which means flags and flag-moderation tools should be working now. It's a big system, though, so there might be things we missed... let us know if you see something else that's broken.